# How can I echo two items per one time by using PHP Foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm using PHP to echo my products from the database. If we just use *foreach*, we will get the result one item per a loop, but actually I want it echo two items per one times as ub the below function.

This is my PHP function using *foreach* to fetch data from database.

I've used ***row item*** selector to wrap ***product*** selector, so I want to echo a block of ***product*** two times, and then it should echo the ***row item***.

Example: row item = 1 then ***product*** = 2

```
public function last_upated_products() {

    $data = $this->newest_products_from_db('products');
    $out = '';
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $row) {

            $out .= '<div class="row item">';

            $out .= '<div class="product">';
            $out .= '<div class="image">';
            $out .= '<a href=""><img src="' . base_url('asset/img/main/9.jpg') . '" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a>';
            $out .= '<div class="promotion"><span class="discount">' . $row['prod_id'] . '% OFF</span> </div>';
            $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '<div class="description"><div class="price"><span>$' . $row['prod_price'] . '</span></div><h4><a href="#">' . $row['prod_name'] . '</a></h4>';
            $out .= '<p>' . $row['prod_descrip'] . '</p>';
            $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '</div>';

            $out .= '</div>';
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

This function will echo one item for a loop.

Comment: you'll have to add a bunch of `if()` code to detect which iteration you're on, and output the "scaffolding" html as appropriate. e.g. `if ($row is odd) { start new div} output stuff; if ($row is even) { end new div}`.

Comment: I'hve test if($k$2 ==0){} But not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not print two times in one iteration of a loop. You can use conditional HTML output to do this job.

Consider this:

```
function last_upated_products() {

    $data = $this->newest_products_from_db('products');
    $out = '';
    $counter = 1;
    $length = count($data);
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $row) {

            if ($counter % 2 != 0) {
                $out .= '<div class="row item">';
            }

            $out .= '<div class="product">';
            $out .= '<div class="image">';
            $out .= '<a href=""><img src="' . base_url('asset/img/main/9.jpg') . '" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a>';
            $out .= '<div class="promotion"><span class="discount">' . $row['prod_id'] . '% OFF</span> </div>';
            $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '<div class="description"><div class="price"><span>$' . $row['prod_price'] . '</span></div><h4><a href="#">' . $row['prod_name'] . '</a></h4>';
            $out .= '<p>' . $row['prod_descrip'] . '</p>';
            $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '</div>';


            if ($counter % 2 == 0 || $length == $counter) {
                $out .= '</div>';
            }

            $counter++;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Will this include the final closing row div when there are an odd number of products?

Comment: @HengSopheak Added final closing `div`

Comment: For odd number of products.

Comment: @Sumit
How can you know that I have trired full day but I can't do it

Comment: Now you will not forget it ;)

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I tested that and it was working fine. The output I get is like 
`<div class="row item">
<div class="product">
</div>
<div class="product">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row item">
<div class="product">
</div>
<div class="product">
</div>
</div>`

Comment: @Sumit my apologies, I shouldn't stackoverflow before coffee. I saw the bottom and didn't realize you started the counter at 1 rather than zero.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Ah Np :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to make the check. If your iterator is a multiple of two it will output the appropriate elements (it does this by checking that the remainder is zero):

```
public function last_upated_products() {

    $data = $this->newest_products_from_db('products');
    $out = '';
    if ($data) {

        $i = 0; 

        foreach ($data as $k => $row) {

            if( ($i % 2) === 0) {
                $out .= '<div class="row item">';
            }
            $out .= '<div class="product">';
            $out .= '<div class="image">';
            $out .= '<a href=""><img src="' . base_url('asset/img/main/9.jpg') . '" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a>';
            $out .= '<div class="promotion"><span class="discount">' . $row['prod_id'] . '% OFF</span> </div>';
            $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '<div class="description"><div class="price"><span>$' . $row['prod_price'] . '</span></div><h4><a href="#">' . $row['prod_name'] . '</a></h4>';
            $out .= '<p>' . $row['prod_descrip'] . '</p>';
            $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '</div>';

            if( ($i + 1) % 2 === 0 || ($i + 1) === count($data) ) {
                $out .= '</div>';
            }

            $i++;
        } 
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Note that the last bit `($i + 1) === count($data)` is important in the event that your set holds an uneven number.

Comment: @HengSopheak indeed, updating.

Comment: @HengSopheak updated, had flawed logic for the closing div previously.

Comment: My god how can you know this logic? I have try more and more time but I can't find the solution why you can guest this code will work for that.
I really want to be a professional like you. How can I do? What is useful website or online course for me to study to improve my knowledge ?